# ExternalQuestion form not displaying on Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, heroku, mechanicalturk

So I'm currently trying to post a HIT to mturk using my rails app and the gem 'rturk'. The entire process works smoothly, except when I open the HIT's amazon url, my rails app's form doesn't show up in the iframe. It's just a blank white iframe. When I check the source of that page, I can clearly see the correct link with assignmentId, hitId, and workerId in it. So there is no reason that it shouldn't be displaying, right? Here is part of the form to display on mturk:

```
<%= form_for @results, :url => 'https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit', html: {class: "takeTest takeScale"} do |f| %>

<%= hidden_field_tag 'assignmentId', @assignment_id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'hitId', @hit_id %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'workerId', @worker_id %>

<%= f.submit("Submit Answers", class: 'btn btn-info') %>
```

And here is part of my controller creating that form as a HIT using rturk:

```
#post to amazon mturk
    RTurk.setup('MYKEY', 'MYOTHERKEY', :sandbox => true)
    @hit = RTurk::Hit.create(:title => "#{@scale.title}") do |hit|
      hit.max_assignments = 5
      hit.description = 'post'
      hit.question("https://my-rails-app.herokuapp.com/tests/scale/take/#{@scale.id}",
                   :frame_height => 500)  # pixels for iframe
      hit.reward = 0.05
      hit.qualifications.add :approval_rate, { :gt => 80 }
    end
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "posted at: #{@hit.url}  !!!"
```

I am wondering if it has something to do with my form or if it is something to do with hosting on heroku? Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the source of an iframe on Amazon by the way, to show that it should all be working:

```
<iframe height="500" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" align="center" src="https://my-rails-app.herokuapp.com/tests/scale/take/7?assignmentId=2IBHSTLB3L0FPI5VSJAEMREVGFBIU0&amp;hitId=2FC98JHSTLB3ZZBONH9OEJEJ4E6FRO&amp;workerId=A1GHEKG3TRCQ5Y&amp;turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fworkersandbox.mturk.com" name="ExternalQuestionIFrame"></iframe>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could it be simply because I haven't explicitly set up my SSL? I reference https and that link works if I go directly to it, so I assumed I didn't need to set it up. Chrome isn't giving me a mixed-content warning, but I think that might be the cause anyway.. Am I onto something?

Comment: I don't think I'm onto anything. "SSL Endpoint is only useful for custom domains. All default appname.herokuapp.com domains are SSL-enabled already and can be accessed simply by using https, e.g., https://appname.herokuapp.com."

Comment: I've got it! If you are experiencing a billion headaches like I am, check this before suffering any further: application.rb in your config directory. If on your mturk HIT page the javascript console gives an x-frame error, add this to your application.rb 

    config.action_dispatch.default_headers.clear

Bam! I'm sure throughout my troubleshooting that I created and solved other problems, but I hope this piece helps you out! Happy turking.

Comment: Confirming AlexTheGoodman's comment also fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to confirm same issue with turkee gem on Rails 4.2

The solution was as @AlexTheGoodman noted in the comments above.

Modify your ~/config/application.rb and add the following:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.action_dispatch.default_headers.clear
end
```